# Failed to get child records without embedded property (JSBIN inside)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would get the records of my field `children`. Here the code:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    online: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.List = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    children: DS.hasMany('App.User'),

    online: function() {
        var users = this.get("children");
        return users.reduce(0, function(previousValue, user){  // no record founds
            return previousValue + user.get("online");
        });
    }.property("children.@each.online")

});
```

But `App.List.find(1).get('online')` returns no record. (For some reason I cannot specify that `App.List.children` contains many records, of type `App.Users`, as **embedded records**).

Here is the fiddle: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/omalib/2/edit) and it's [output](http://jsbin.com/omalib/2/)
How I can solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the embedded Model on your Adapter map:

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  users: DS.hasMany('App.User'), //use "users" as the property name to mantain ember's naming conventions
  ...
});

App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();

App.Adapter.map('App.List', {
  users: {embedded: 'always'} //you can use `always` or `load` which is lazy loading.
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter:  App.Adapter.create()
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! I knew the **embedded** features, but I thought that the JSON loading should be of the type:
    {
     "lists": [
                                     { "id": 0, "name" : "Frinds", "users" : [ { "id": 1, "username": "user1", "online":false } , { "id": 2, "username": "user2", "online":true }, { "id": 3, "username": "user3", "online":true }] },
                                     ...
                             ],
    }

I updated my JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/ayedoz/1

Comment: Only one thing I can not understand. After running the population, it is also inserted an empty list record (with no id). To verify: `JSON.stringify(App.List.find().toArray())` returns: `"[{" name ": null}, {" name ":" Frinds "}, {" name ":" Work "}]"` http://jsbin.com/ayedoz/1